# find child node title's text equel a value

Tags: c#

How do i find `SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNames` title's value equel  'test' in one line?
I don't write linq it doesn't work.

```
   protected SiteMapNodeCollection getParentNodeTitle()
   {
        SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNames            
   }
```

Comment: There's no ChildNames in `SiteMapNode`. There's `ChildNodes`, oth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var mySiteMap = new SiteMap();
/* Lots of code for populating your SiteMap here */

var nodeTitledTest = mySiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes.Where(x => x.Title == "test").FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the first node with a title equal to "test" or null if no such node could be found.

Comment: A proper solution would be recursive given that a sitemap is a tree structure, however, OP could be using his own data structure.

Comment: My intention was to give him a nudge in the right direction, not the complete solution :) His question wasn't very good, he stated that linq doesn't work and never provided any data regarding his attempt at that.

Comment: Also do it like that : `var nodeTitledTest = SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>().First(x => x.Title == "test");`

Comment: Pretty sure that your example is equal to mine @Özkan

Comment: It's not equel to yours @Maritim You could see http://i.imgur.com/ObcmveK.png